# Returning different type via generics in C#

Tags: c#, generics, return-type

My generic extension method signature:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<R> DoThing<T, R>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
        where T : class
        where R : class
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

My usage pattern:

```
List<MyItem> codes = new List<MyItem>();
List<MyNewItem> newValues = codes.Where(o => o.Property== 1).DoThing<MyItem, MyNewItem>();
```

codes.Where should result in an IQueryable< T > output, it's the normal System.Linq namespace.

Results in:

<s>'IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'DoThing' and no extension method 'DoThing' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)</s>

I needed to specify both Types, T and R, as it turns out.

Thank you, all for the help!

Comment: Is the class containing `DoThing` static?

Comment: Yes, sorry for not including that - I'll add it now.

Comment: Either way I didn't notice your typing earlier. I think pm100 has posted the correct solution here

Comment: Re: your update: MyItems is not queryable. Or you haven't got the queryable version of Where in scope. Or there is another Where in scope that returns something other than a queryable. There is not enough information in the question to deduce which case you're in, but you're in one of them.

Comment: Queryable version of Where in scope?  I thought System.Linq .Where extension returned an IQueryable<T>?  So my thought was that my extension method should be able to take IQueryable<T> and allow me to output IQueryable<R>  based on DoThing<T,R>.

Comment: Well, that's a scientific hypothesis. **Test it with science**. What's the return type of that Where? You've given me no indication that `System.Linq` extensions are in scope.

Comment: For example: can you assign the return value of that `Where` to a variable of queryable type? Can you assign MyItems to a variable of queryable type? Do an experiment and find out.

Comment: I can assign it to an IQueryable<MyItem>...  after realizing that I had the wrong namespace.   Wow.  I need to clean up my Experimentation project!

Comment: So what question is this question now asking?

Comment: No further questions at this time.  I'm working on cleaning it up.

Comment: If you have an interest in the method type inference algorithm, I have written a number of articles about it over the years. There are considerable subtleties to it.

Comment: That's going to be tomorrow after work - I started down that path of looking into the method type inference system already, and quickly realized I'd be up all night if I start reading up on it now!  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

you must either specify no Types or all of them

do this

```
List<MyNewItem> newValues = codes.Where(o => o.Property== 1).DoThing();
```

that wont work with the code you show (cos it doesnt return anything) but if you fix it it probably will. Else do this

```
List<MyNewItem> newValues = codes.Where(o => o.Property== 1).DoThing<MyNewItem, MyItem>();
```

Comment: That handles my IEnumerable<T> scenario - thank you!  I'm trying to figure out why the same doesn't work for IQueryable<T> :)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do *partial* method type inference in C#.  It would be nice if you could, but you can't.  Your choices are to either provide the entire list of type arguments for the method call, or none of them and have them deduced.

In your case type inference will *never* deduce the type of `R` because type inference only looks at *arguments* and *formals* and there is no formal that uses `R`.

Looking more specifically at your scenario: I cannot for the life of me see what the body of your method could possibly be; it must create a sequence of `R` out of a sequence of `T`.  OK, let's suppose `T` is `Giraffe` and `R` is `Comparer<Nullable<Rectangle>>`. How on earth are you going to get a bunch of nullable rectangle comparers out of a bunch of giraffes?

You are almost certainly doing something *very wrong* here.  Typically you would provide a function to do that. That's why the signature of `Select` is

```
public static IEnumerable<R> Select<A, R>(
  this IEnumerable<A> items, 
  Func<A, R> projection)
```

Now there is enough compile time information for the compiler to deduce both `A` and `R` from the call site arguments, and there is a way to get a sequence of `R` out of a sequence of `A`, by calling the projection on each `A`.

Comment: This is an extremely simplistic example, just to get the method signature correct.  I'll be adding 'where T : MyInterface where R : MyReturnInterface'.  I'm intending to map between known classes.

Comment: @John: Then why do you need a generic method at all?  Why isn't your method simply `IEnumerable<IMyReturn> DoThing(IEnumerable<IMyThing>)` ?

Comment: @John: Besides, that doesn't solve the problem. Here, I'll make Giraffe implement `IMyReturn` and I'll make `Comparer<Nullable<Rectangle>>` implement `IMyInterface` and now we're in the same boat as before. You've got a bunch of giraffes; how are you going to get a bunch of nullable rectangle comparers out of them?  Again: you are probably doing something wrong here; we can tell just by the signature of the method.

Comment: I'm not saying there's not better ways of accomplishing what I'm attempting here.  This is me learning is all :)

Comment: @John: I'm not making any claims of what way would be better, or that there is a better way. I'm saying that the signature of your method indicates that to me that your method either does *nothing* or does something *impossible* or uses some *really bad programming practice*. You probably believe that your method does something sensible. One of us is wrong.

Comment: Most likely it does an impossibly bad programming practice.  I'm exploring here, nothing more.  This isn't production code going anywhere or anything of the like.  This is my curiosity about a clear gap in my own understanding, nothing more.